# how do i solve this EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x0bbadbeef)

Tags: ios, multithreading

[screenshot :: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQCka.png)]
My App isn't running and I am getting following on the console:

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x16632500: Tried to obtain the web lock
>   from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may
>   be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing
>   now...

```
1   0x27db3da1 WebThreadLock
2   0x2899a4eb <redacted>
3   0x24ef5af5 __NSFireDelayedPerform
4   0x2469a58f <redacted>
5   0x2469a1c1 <redacted>
6   0x2469800d <redacted>
7   0x245e7229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
8   0x24627dd3 CFRunLoopRun
9   0xaf1f9 -[RenderLoop threadMain]
10  0x24f014a5 <redacted>
11  0x2440b85b <redacted>
12  0x2440b7cf _pthread_start
13  0x24409724 thread_start
```

Comment: Are you making calls to update UI content from a background thread or queue?

Comment: Error seems that you are performing UI related task on thread other than main thread. Update your code when you get crash so anyone can solve it.

Comment: Before solving comes understanding the problem. And before understanding often comes reading. So read the error message. ... read it again ... now the problem should be clear and the solution can only be found by looking at your code.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint: In the breakpoint pane of Xcode, click the „+“ bottom left. Choose „Add Exception Breakpoint“, and close the appearing window by clicking outside. Next time you run your app, it will stop at the critical instruction.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to update UIcontent from a background thread but it should have been updated on main thread.For doing so this worked for me.

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod:)withObject:obj waitUntilDone:YES]
```

but it slows down my background thread which is rendering an OpenGL content.